# Create an empty data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, r-faq

I'm trying to initialize a data.frame without any rows. Basically, I want to specify the data types for each column and name them, but not have any rows created as a result.

The best I've been able to do so far is something like:

```
df <- data.frame(Date=as.Date("01/01/2000", format="%m/%d/%Y"), 
                 File="", User="", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df <- df[-1,]
```

Which creates a data.frame with a single row containing all of the data types and column names I wanted, but also creates a useless row which then needs to be removed.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 792, accepted):

Just initialize it with empty vectors:

```
df <- data.frame(Date=as.Date(character()),
                 File=character(), 
                 User=character(), 
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

---

Here's an other example with different column types :

```
df <- data.frame(Doubles=double(),
                 Ints=integer(),
                 Factors=factor(),
                 Logicals=logical(),
                 Characters=character(),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

str(df)
> str(df)
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Doubles   : num 
 $ Ints      : int 
 $ Factors   : Factor w/ 0 levels: 
 $ Logicals  : logi 
 $ Characters: chr
```

**N.B. :**

Initializing a `data.frame` with an empty column of the wrong type does not prevent further additions of rows having columns of different types.
This method is just a bit *safer* in the sense that you'll have the correct column types from the beginning, hence if your code relies on some column type checking, it will work even with a `data.frame` with zero rows.

Comment: Would it be the same if I initialize all fields with NULL?

Comment: @yosukesabai: no, if you initialize a column with NULL the column won't be added :)

Comment: I see that...  why I thought it would work...?  So this means I have to know type of data on each column ahead of time and initialize properly?

Comment: @yosukesabai: `data.frame`'s have typed columns, so yes, if you want to initialize a `data.frame` you must decide the type of the columns...

Comment: For the sake of completeness this would be good to give a second example with all the possible primitive types that could be assumed to make this answer a solid reference.

Comment: @jxramos: well, actually `data.frame` is not really restrictive on the "primitivity" of the columns types (for example, you can add a column of dates or even a column containing list of elements). Also, this question is not an absolute reference, since for example if you don't specify the correct type of the column you will not block further row addition having column of different types... so, I will add a note, but not an example with all primitive types because it does not cover all the possibilities...

Comment: That's all good and true, the initially specified type is not a limiting contract for any given column but it's still useful for communicating intent and whatever degree of readability it offers. I wound up using your example with some double() columns in my application, which funnily enough was written by another using pretty much the same approach as the Question author's solution. I too wanted to see an easier way to do it without recourse to a throwaway row. Exhaustive coverage may be too much, but a good sampling beyond character seems reasonable too.

Comment: @digEmAll how do you specify the number of rows?

Comment: @user4050: the question was about creating an empty data.frame, so when the number of rows is zero...maybe you want to create a data.frame full on NAs... in that case you can use e.g. `data.frame(Doubles=rep(as.double(NA),numberOfRow),           Ints=rep(as.integer(NA),numberOfRow))`

Comment: Without ``stringsAsFactors=FALSE``, ``character()`` is constrained to a factor! ``str(data.frame(a=character()))
'data.frame': 0 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ a: Factor w/ 0 levels:``

Comment: Yes, that's why I set that parameter

Comment: how do you append to such a data frame without triggering `data has 0` rows error?

Comment: @MikePalmice: use `rbind` or `DF[nrow(DF)+1,] <- the row to append`

Comment: @digEmAll is there any advantage of creating empty data frame vs empty but with `NA`s vs actually **filled** with `NA`s?

Comment: @vasili111: they are different approach for different situations. For instance a data.frame preallocated with NAs is applicable only when you know the number of rows in advance; in this case may be more efficient but really it depends on the problem you're going to solve

Answer (score 205):

If you **already have an existent data frame**, let's say `df` that has the columns you want, then you can just create an empty data frame by removing all the rows:

```
empty_df = df[FALSE,]
```

Notice that `df` still contains the data, but `empty_df` doesn't.

I found this question looking for how to create a new instance with empty rows, so I think it might be helpful for some people.

Comment: Wonderful idea. Keep none of the rows, but ALL the columns. Whoever downvoted missed something.

Comment: Nice solution, however I found that I get a data frame with 0 rows. In order to keep the size of the data frame the same, I suggest new_df = df[NA,]. This also allows to store any previous column into the new data frame. For example to obtain the "Date" column from original df (while keeping rest NA): new_df$Date <- df$Date.

Comment: @Katya, if you do `df[NA,]` this will affect the index as well (which is unlikely to be what you want), I would instead use `df[TRUE,] = NA`; however notice that this will overwrite the original. You will need to copy the dataframe first `copy_df = data.frame(df)` and then `copy_df[TRUE,] = NA`

Comment: @Katya, or you can also easily add empty rows to the `empty_df` with `empty_df[0:nrow(df),] <- NA`.

Comment: toto_tico, thank you for the additions, indeed the labels were affected, so I deleted them with: row.names(df) <- c(). 
However I think that your suggestion is better, because it allowed to create the correct size df with col names and correct row names: newDf <- df then newDf[,]<-NA
By the way, how do you get your typed code to come up in grey? :-)

Comment: @Katya, you use a the backquote  (\`) around what you would like to mark as code, and there is other stuff as *italics* using \*, and **bold** using \*\*. You probably want to read all the [Markdown Syntax of SO](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Most of it only make sense for answers though.

Comment: @toto_tico This is a great solution! Save typing out potentially a large number of columns. +1

Comment: `empty_df = df[FALSE,]` creates an `numeric (empty)` instead of retaining the `dataframe` type, has this behaviour been changed since this solution was added?

Comment: @LarryCai, could you post a small example? I tested the one in the question `df <- data.frame(Date=as.Date("01/01/2000", format="%m/%d/%Y"), File="", User="", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`, and still works for me.

Answer (score 90):

You can do it without specifying column types

```
df = data.frame(matrix(vector(), 0, 3,
                dimnames=list(c(), c("Date", "File", "User"))),
                stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Comment: In that case, the column types default as logical per vector(), but are then overridden with the types of the elements added to df.  Try str(df), df[1,1]<-'x'

Answer (score 70):

You could use `read.table` with an empty string for the input `text` as follows:

```
colClasses = c("Date", "character", "character")
col.names = c("Date", "File", "User")

df <- read.table(text = "",
                 colClasses = colClasses,
                 col.names = col.names)
```

Alternatively specifying the `col.names` as a string:

```
df <- read.csv(text="Date,File,User", colClasses = colClasses)
```

Thanks to Richard Scriven for the improvement

Comment: Or even `read.table(text = "", ...)` so you don't need to explicitly open a connection.

Comment: snazzy. probably the most extensible/automable way of doing this for _many_ potential columns

Comment: The `read.csv` approach also works with `readr::read_csv`, as in `read_csv("Date,File,User\n", col_types = "Dcc")`. This way you can directly create an empty tibble of the required structure.

Answer (score 56):

Just declare

```
table = data.frame()
```

when you try to `rbind` the first line it will create the columns

Comment: Doesn't really meet the OP's requirements of "I want to specify the data types for each column and name them". *If* the next step is an `rbind` this would work well, if not...

Comment: Anyway, thanks for this simple solution. I wanted also to initialize a data.frame with specific columns since I thought rbind can only be used if the columns corresponds between the two data.frame. This seems not to be the case. I was surprised that I can so simply initialize a data.frame when using rbind. Thanks.

Comment: The best proposed solution here. For me, using the proposed way, worked perfectly with `rbind()`.

Answer (score 30):

The most efficient way to do this is to use `structure` to create a list that has the class `"data.frame"`:

```
structure(list(Date = as.Date(character()), File = character(), User = character()), 
          class = "data.frame")
# [1] Date File User
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

To put this into perspective compared to the presently accepted answer, here's a simple benchmark:

```
s <- function() structure(list(Date = as.Date(character()), 
                               File = character(), 
                               User = character()), 
                          class = "data.frame")
d <- function() data.frame(Date = as.Date(character()),
                           File = character(), 
                           User = character(), 
                           stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
library("microbenchmark")
microbenchmark(s(), d())
# Unit: microseconds
#  expr     min       lq     mean   median      uq      max neval
#   s()  58.503  66.5860  90.7682  82.1735 101.803  469.560   100
#   d() 370.644 382.5755 523.3397 420.1025 604.654 1565.711   100
```

Comment: `data.table` is usually contains a `.internal.selfref` attribute, which cannot be faked without calling the `data.table` functions. Are you sure you are not relying on an undocumented behavior here?

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski I think you're confusing the base "data.frame" class and the add-on "data.table" class from the [data.table package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=data.table).

Comment: Yes. Definitely. My bad. Ignore my last comment. I came across this thread when searching for the `data.table` and assumed that Google did find what I wanted and everything here is `data.table`-related.

Comment: @PatrickT There's no checking that what your code is doing makes any sense. `data.frame()` provides checks on naming, rownames, etc.

Answer (score 17):

If you are looking for shortness :

```
read.csv(text="col1,col2")
```

so you don't need to specify the column names separately. You get the default column type logical until you fill the data frame.

Comment: read.csv parses the text argument so you get the column names. It is more compact than read.table(text="", col.names = c("col1", "col2"))

Comment: I get : `Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 2`

Comment: This doesn't meet OP's requirements, *"I want to specify the data types for each column"*, though it could probably be modified to do so.

Comment: Very late for the party but `readr` can do it: `read_csv2("a;b;c;d;e\n", col_types = "icdDT")`. There need to be `\n` to regognize it is string not a file (or use `c("a;b;c;d;e", "")`. As a bonus column names won't be modified (e.g. `col-1` or `why spaces`)

Answer (score 15):

I created empty data frame using following code

```
df = data.frame(id = numeric(0), jobs = numeric(0));
```

and tried to bind some rows to populate the same as follows.

```
newrow = c(3, 4)
df <- rbind(df, newrow)
```

but it started giving incorrect column names as follows

```
  X3 X4
1  3  4
```

Solution to this is to convert newrow to type df as follows

```
newrow = data.frame(id=3, jobs=4)
df <- rbind(df, newrow)
```

now gives correct data frame when displayed with column names as follows

```
  id nobs
1  3   4
```

Answer (score 9):

To **create an empty data frame**, pass in the number of rows and columns needed into the following function:

```
create_empty_table <- function(num_rows, num_cols) {
    frame <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = num_rows, ncol = num_cols))
    return(frame)
}
```

To create an empty frame **while specifying the class of each column**, simply pass a vector of the desired data types into the following function:

```
create_empty_table <- function(num_rows, num_cols, type_vec) {
  frame <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = num_rows, ncol = num_cols))
  for(i in 1:ncol(frame)) {
    print(type_vec[i])
    if(type_vec[i] == 'numeric') {frame[,i] <- as.numeric(frame[,i])}
    if(type_vec[i] == 'character') {frame[,i] <- as.character(frame[,i])}
    if(type_vec[i] == 'logical') {frame[,i] <- as.logical(frame[,i])}
    if(type_vec[i] == 'factor') {frame[,i] <- as.factor(frame[,i])}
  }
  return(frame)
}
```

Use as follows:

```
df <- create_empty_table(3, 3, c('character','logical','numeric'))
```

Which gives:

```
   X1  X2 X3
1 <NA> NA NA
2 <NA> NA NA
3 <NA> NA NA
```

To confirm your choices, run the following:

```
lapply(df, class)

#output
$X1
[1] "character"

$X2
[1] "logical"

$X3
[1] "numeric"
```

Comment: This doesn't meet OP's requirements, *"I want to specify the data types for each column"*

Answer (score 7):

If you want to create an empty data.frame with dynamic names (colnames in a variable), this can help:

```
names <- c("v","u","w")
df <- data.frame()
for (k in names) df[[k]]<-as.numeric()
```

You can change the types as well if you need so. like:

```
names <- c("u", "v")
df <- data.frame()
df[[names[1]]] <- as.numeric()
df[[names[2]]] <- as.character()
```

Answer (score 7):

By Using `data.table` we can specify data types for each column.

```
library(data.table)    
data=data.table(a=numeric(), b=numeric(), c=numeric())
```

Answer (score 6):

If you don't mind not specifying data types explicitly, you can do it this way:

```
headers<-c("Date","File","User")
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(,ncol=3,nrow=0))
names(df)<-headers

#then bind incoming data frame with col types to set data types
df<-rbind(df, new_df)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to declare such a `data.frame` with many columns, it'll probably be a pain to type all the column classes out by hand. Especially if you can make use of `rep`, this approach is easy and fast (about 15% faster than the other solution that can be generalized like this):

If your desired column classes are in a vector `colClasses`, you can do the following:

```
library(data.table)
setnames(setDF(lapply(colClasses, function(x) eval(call(x)))), col.names)
```

`lapply` will result in a list of desired length, each element of which is simply an empty typed vector like `numeric()` or `integer()`.

`setDF` converts this `list` by reference to a `data.frame`.

`setnames` adds the desired names by reference.

Speed comparison:

```
classes <- c("character", "numeric", "factor",
             "integer", "logical","raw", "complex")

NN <- 300
colClasses <- sample(classes, NN, replace = TRUE)
col.names <- paste0("V", 1:NN)

setDF(lapply(colClasses, function(x) eval(call(x))))

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(times = 1000,
               read = read.table(text = "", colClasses = colClasses,
                                 col.names = col.names),
               DT = setnames(setDF(lapply(colClasses, function(x)
                 eval(call(x)))), col.names))
# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#  read 2.598226 2.707445 3.247340 2.747835 2.800134 22.46545  1000   b
#    DT 2.257448 2.357754 2.895453 2.401408 2.453778 17.20883  1000  a
```

It's also faster than using `structure` in a similar way:

```
microbenchmark(times = 1000,
               DT = setnames(setDF(lapply(colClasses, function(x)
                 eval(call(x)))), col.names),
               struct = eval(parse(text=paste0(
                 "structure(list(", 
                 paste(paste0(col.names, "=", 
                              colClasses, "()"), collapse = ","),
                 "), class = \"data.frame\")"))))
#Unit: milliseconds
#   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
#     DT 2.068121 2.167180 2.821868 2.211214 2.268569 143.70901  1000  a 
# struct 2.613944 2.723053 3.177748 2.767746 2.831422  21.44862  1000   b
```

Answer (score 3):

If you already have a dataframe, you can **extract the metadata (column names and types)** from a dataframe (e.g. if **you are controlling a BUG** which is only triggered with certain inputs and need a empty dummy Dataframe):

```
colums_and_types <- sapply(df, class)

# prints: "c('col1', 'col2')"
print(dput(as.character(names(colums_and_types))))

# prints: "c('integer', 'factor')"
dput(as.character(as.vector(colums_and_types)))
```

And then use the `read.table` to create the empty dataframe

```
read.table(text = "",
   colClasses = c('integer', 'factor'),
   col.names = c('col1', 'col2'))
```

Answer (score 2):

I keep this function handy for whenever I need it, and change the column names and classes to suit the use case:

```
make_df <- function() { data.frame(name=character(),
                     profile=character(),
                     sector=character(),
                     type=character(),
                     year_range=character(),
                     link=character(),
                     stringsAsFactors = F)
}

make_df()
[1] name       profile    sector     type       year_range link      
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Answer (score 1):

Say your column names are dynamic, you can create an empty row-named matrix and transform it to a data frame.

```
nms <- sample(LETTERS,sample(1:10))
as.data.frame(t(matrix(nrow=length(nms),ncol=0,dimnames=list(nms))))
```

Comment: This doesn't meet OP's requirements, *"I want to specify the data types for each column"*

Answer (score 1):

This question didn't specifically address my concerns (outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52844649/how-to-set-the-types-of-columns-in-an-empty-data-frame)) but in case anyone wants to do this with a parameterized number of columns and no coercion:

```
> require(dplyr)
> dbNames <- c('a','b','c','d')
> emptyTableOut <- 
    data.frame(
        character(), 
        matrix(integer(), ncol = 3, nrow = 0), stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    ) %>% 
    setNames(nm = c(dbNames))
> glimpse(emptyTableOut)
Observations: 0
Variables: 4
$ a <chr> 
$ b <int> 
$ c <int> 
$ d <int>
```

As divibisan states on the linked question,

> ...the reason [coercion] occurs [when cbinding matrices and their constituent types] is that a matrix can only have a
>   single data type. When you cbind 2 matrices, the result is still a
>   matrix and so the variables are all coerced into a single type before
>   converting to a data.frame