# How to create empty data frame with column names specified in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create an Empty Data.Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689055/create-an-empty-data-frame)

I need to create an empty data frame in R with specified column names. Any simplest way ?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Just create a `data.frame` with 0 length variables

eg

```
nodata <- data.frame(x= numeric(0), y= integer(0), z = character(0))
str(nodata)

## 'data.frame':    0 obs. of  3 variables:
##  $ x: num 
##  $ y: int 
##  $ z: Factor w/ 0 levels:
```

or to create a data.frame with 5 columns named a,b,c,d,e

```
nodata <- as.data.frame(setNames(replicate(5,numeric(0), simplify = F), letters[1:5]))
```

Comment: why does z convert to Factor?

Comment: @pssguy because of the default behaviour of data.frame, and specifically the default value for the argument stringsAsFactors = T.

Answer (score 16):

Perhaps:

```
> data.frame(aname=NA, bname=NA)[numeric(0), ]
[1] aname bname
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```