# Dynamically allocate a data.frame with grace

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame supposed to grow (adding rows) during runtime. It is wise to pre-allocate the data frame beforehand (cmp. [The R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/documents/books/the-r-inferno/)). The pre-allocation routine should accept all kinds of data frame composition (i.e. number of columns and column classes).

**Example**

```
arbitraryDf<-function(){
    return(data.frame(C="char",L=TRUE,N=4.5,stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
}
```

returns an arbitrary data frame to use as template. I will need `N <- 10` rows, so I might do:

```
data<-as.data.frame(lapply(arbitraryDf(),function(x){eval(parse(text=paste(class(x),"(",N,")")))}),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

which returns the desired data frame.

```
>data
   C     L N
1    FALSE 0
2    FALSE 0
3    FALSE 0
4    FALSE 0
5    FALSE 0
6    FALSE 0
7    FALSE 0
8    FALSE 0
9    FALSE 0
10   FALSE 0
>sapply(data,class)
          C           L           N 
"character"   "logical"   "numeric"
```

Needless to say, the use of `eval()` is ugly. Is there a more straightforward solution to this?

As said, the routine needs to accept any data frame composition, otherwise  [@mnel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613909/how-to-create-empty-data-frame-with-column-names-specified-in-r) was good enough.

**Update**

Essentially, I would like to achieve the same as

```
data <- data.frame(x= numeric(N), y= integer(N), z = character(N))
```

but in a generic way, for any df layout. The info of the df layout should be drawn from a given df (here arbitraryDf())

Comment: Are you looking for something like `do.call(rbind, replicate(N, arbitraryDf(), FALSE))`? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @Ananda As said, the goal is to allocate a data frame. Column number and classes will not be known before runtime. Your solution is nice, but also replicates the the content of the data.frame

Comment: I would be using the `vector` function to allocate, but you don't provide enough detail to advise properly, your use-case is not well explained. I don't see there being any difference in `rbind`ing a complete row as opposed to `[<-` subset and replace. If you *had* to preallocate I'd be looking at e.g. `N <- 10;df <- data.frame( n = vector("numeric",N) , c = vector("character",N) )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort of generalize Simon's comment, perhaps something like this would be of use to you:

```
myFun <- function(sourceDF, length) {
  Classes <- sapply(sourceDF, class)
  data.frame(lapply(Classes, vector, length = length))
}
```

Here, we first extract the classes of each column of the source `data.frame` and use that as a template for the new `data.frame`, whose length is determined by the `length` argument.

Example:

```
myFun(arbitraryDf(), 5)
#   C     L N
# 1   FALSE 0
# 2   FALSE 0
# 3   FALSE 0
# 4   FALSE 0
# 5   FALSE 0
```

Comment: +1, *but* is there really a performance enhancement from preallocating and then (I assume) subset and replace rows, rather than just rbinding them? I doubt it (but I haven't tested that).

Comment: @Ananda. Very nice. Just to be sure, the return value should read: `data.frame(...,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`, since for factors you wouldn't be able to insert any values without adding new levels

Comment: Yes, @Simon, definitely & drastically. Refer to [R-Inferno p12 for timings](http://www.burns-stat.com/documents/books/the-r-inferno/)

Comment: @Jan, I don't think that Simon is questioning the value of preallocation, but whether this is the best solution to your problem (which I still don't fully understand).

Comment: @Ananda, maybe my fault. It goes without saying, above is just a play example -- maybe not a good one. The did `rbind`ing and now improve by allocating and subsetting. It's alot faster. Especially on big datasets. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this what you are looking for. The function `gendf` takes two arguments -- the template data frame and the number of rows. It returns empty data frame according to the template with given number of rows.

```
arbitraryDf <- data.frame(C = "char", L = T, N = 4.5, stringsAsFactors = F)
arbitraryDf

gendf <- function(df, N) {
  # Create list of modes
  modes <- lapply(df, storage.mode)
  # Return data.frame
  return(data.frame(lapply(modes, vector, N)))
}

x <- gendf(arbitraryDf, 10)
class(x)
```

Comment: Unlucky. Looks like Ananda pipped you by 8 seconds! +1 anyway.