# How to initialize empty data frame (lot of columns at the same time) in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I found how to initialize an empty data frame with 3 or 4 dimensions.  It's like

```
df <- data.frame(Date=as.Date(character()),
             File=character(), 
             User=numeric(), 
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

However,  What's the most effective way to initialize an empty data.frame with a lot of column names. like

```
mynames <- paste("hello", c(1:10000))
```

The wrong way I tried is:

```
df <- data.frame(mynames=numeric())
```

Thanks a lot beforehand

Comment: Related: [*Create an empty data.frame*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689055/create-an-empty-data-frame)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Maybe this -

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 10000, nrow = 0))
colnames(df) <- paste0("hello", c(1:10000))
```

And @joran's suggestion - `df <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = 10000, nrow = 0)),paste0("hello", c(1:10000)))`

Comment: yeah.  This sounds right.  I guess what I need is a matrix and not a data.frame.  Thanks

Comment: If you really wanted to force it into one line, you could use `setNames`.

Comment: @WilmerEHenaoH, consider accepting the answer if it solves the problem. joran, good idea, updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using `setDF` (or `setDT`, if you prefer `data.table` as output) and `setnames`:

```
library(data.table)

DF <- setnames(setDF(lapply(integer(1e4), function(...) character(0L))),
               paste0("hello", 1:1e4))
head(names(DF))
# [1] "hello1" "hello2" "hello3" "hello4" "hello5" "hello6"
```

Both steps (`setnames` and `setDF`) are more efficient than the `base` counterparts, since no copies are made.

A benchmark:

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(times = 1000,
               base = {df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 10000, nrow = 0))
               colnames(df) <- paste0("hello", c(1:10000))},
               DT = setnames(setDF(lapply(integer(1e4), 
                                          function(...) character(0L))),
                             paste0("hello", 1:1e4)))
# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#  base 26.77218 30.94223 37.30173 36.76721 37.80338 102.2379  1000   b
#    DT 16.68004 23.18865 30.60573 29.18421 36.03590 178.1045  1000  a
```