# How to initialize empty data frame where number of columns is depends on multiple input parameters in R

Tags: r, list, function, loops

i need to create an empty data.table, with a variable length. For example, i will be given that `n = 2` amd `m = 12`, then i want the table to have columns such as:

```
name, ID, nickname, start_1, start_2, count_1, count_2, value_<n>_month_<m>
```

(`value_<n>_month_<m>` is repeated `m` x `n` times)

i get columns: `name, ID, nickname, start_1, start_2, start_3 count_1, count_2, count_3` by using the following code:

```
  VarStart <- setnames(setDF(lapply(integer(K), function(...) character(0L))),
                               paste0("start", 1:K))
   NewTable <- cbind(NewTable, VarStart)
  VarCount <- setnames(setDF(lapply(integer(K), function(...) character(0L))),
                               paste0("start", 1:K))
   NewTable <- cbind(NewTable, VarCount)
```

borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20501345/how-to-initialize-empty-data-frame-lot-of-columns-at-the-same-time-in-r).

But how can i crete columns for variables with both `n` and `m` in the column name?

Is there a nicer way to what i already have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
n = 2
m = 12

const_col <- c('name', 'ID', 'nickname')
sc_cols <- c(t(outer(c('start', 'count'), seq_len(n),paste0)))
vm_cols <- c(t(outer(seq_len(n), seq_len(m), function(x, y) 
                  sprintf('value_%d_month_%d', x, y))))
all_cols <- c(const_col, sc_cols, vm_cols)

NewTable <- data.table::data.table(matrix(ncol = length(all_cols), 
                         dimnames = list(NULL, all_cols)))
```

Specify `nrow` as 0 if you want an empty data.table with 0 rows.

```
names(NewTable)
# [1] "name"             "ID"               "nickname"        
# [4] "start1"           "start2"           "count1"          
# [7] "count2"           "value_1_month_1"  "value_1_month_2" 
#[10] "value_1_month_3"  "value_1_month_4"  "value_1_month_5" 
#[13] "value_1_month_6"  "value_1_month_7"  "value_1_month_8" 
#[16] "value_1_month_9"  "value_1_month_10" "value_1_month_11"
#[19] "value_1_month_12" "value_2_month_1"  "value_2_month_2" 
#[22] "value_2_month_3"  "value_2_month_4"  "value_2_month_5" 
#[25] "value_2_month_6"  "value_2_month_7"  "value_2_month_8" 
#[28] "value_2_month_9"  "value_2_month_10" "value_2_month_11"
#[31] "value_2_month_12"
```

Comment: i get an table with one row (all NA), and all columns are of class logi

Comment: Yes, so what do you expect as output then?

Comment: i am just surprised, i guess i expected empty character strings for some reason. Is there a reason why they are logi? like a default setting?

Comment: Well, we have not initialized any value in matrix which gives by default `NA` value and `class(NA)` is logical. You can have any values that you want, For example to get empty string values, you can do : `data.table::data.table(matrix('', ncol = length(all_cols), 
                              dimnames = list(NULL, all_cols)))` , replace `''` with `NA_integer_` or  `NA_character_` to get integer and character columns.