# How do I create an empty vector of dates?

Tags: r, vector

Is it possible to create an empty vector of dates in r?

I can create an empty vector of integers, doubles, logicals etc:

```
> integer()
integer(0)
> double()
numeric(0)
> logical()
logical(0)
> length(integer())
[1] 0
```

but this meme doesn't work for dates, as `date()` returns the current system date and time. So, how would I create an emtpy vector of dates?

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689055/create-an-empty-data-frame)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just add a class attribute to a length-0 interger and it's a Date (at least it will appear to be one if you extend it with values that are sensible when interpreted as R-Dates):

```
>  x <- integer(0)
> x
integer(0)
> class(x) <- "Date"
> x
character(0)
> class(x)
[1] "Date"
> y <- c(x, 1400)
> y
[1] "1973-11-01"
```

The output from `as.Date` happens to be a character value so the first call is a bit misleading.

```
> as.Date(integer())
character(0)
> str( as.Date(integer()) )
Class 'Date'  num(0) 
> dput( as.Date(integer()) )
structure(numeric(0), class = "Date")
```

Comment: In my case : `> as.Date(x = integer(0))` returns an error : `Error in as.Date.numeric(x = integer(0)) : 'origin' must be supplied`. I've to supply origin : `as.Date(x = integer(0), origin = "1970-01-01")` works !

Comment: It's not the method I demonstrated, which continues to succeed. The behavior of `as.Date(integer())` appears to have changed. It now returns the error you demonstrated. I'm unable to find an entry in the NEWS file that explains that change.

Answer (score 19):

With recent versions of R, you have to supply the origin :

```
as.Date(x = integer(0), origin = "1970-01-01")
```

Answer (score 9):

Using the lubridate package and deciding what your intended format will be (eg. yyyy/mm/dd) you can use:

```
lubridate::ymd()
# or
lubridate::mdy()
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to work and saves a few keystrokes relative to some of the other answers:

```
> as.Date(character(0))
Date of length 0
```