# Create a data frame from a set of vectors

Tags: r

I need to be able to create a data frame from a set of passed in parameters. I realize I can hand type this, but I'm simplifying for the purposes of the question.

Given two vectors:

```
names <- c('Name', 'Height', 'DateOfBirth') 
types <- c('character', 'integer', 'POSIXct')
```

How can I create a data frame with those names and data types?
This works, but it creates everything as characters:

```
myDataFrame <- as.data.frame(setNames(replicate(length(myNames),character(0)), myNames))
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
myDataFrame <- as.data.frame(setNames(types, names))
```

I've searched and don't see anything. The `setNames` function came from searching.

Comment: I think [this is a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10689055/903061). Though not all the answers meet your criteria, Floo0's does: `read.table(text = "", colClasses = types, col.names = names)`

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't seen Floo0's answer before. Is proper etiquette to leave this question so it re-directs others to the linked answer you gave, or does a duplicate count toward the unanswered count and should therefore be deleted? I know I've found things before by stumbling across the duplicate and then finding the original answer, but wasn't sure on what is proper.

Comment: Yup! Flagging as a duplicate is intended to serve as a helpful pointer.