# How do I insert 3 vectors in the same row of a dataframe?

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I'm new in R and I have a problem. I created an "empty" data.frame, as in R I cannot do this, I created a vector to fulfil it that I would delete when finishing the script.

```
x <- c("aa", 0, 0, 0, "zz") #Vector to fulfill the dataframe (it will be deleted at the end of the script)       
df <<- rbind(x) #Creating a matrix. See: class(df)    
df <<- data.frame(df) #Converting the matrix into a data.frame
```

But now I need to fulfil that dataframe with three vectors:

```
a <- c("bb")       
b <- c(2, 3, 4)    
c <- c("yy")
```

The desired output is a dataframe like this:

```
    X1  X2  X3  X4  X5

r1  aa  0   0   0   zz

r2  bb  2   3   4   yy
```

I have tried this: `df <- rbind(df, a, b, c)` but it does not work...

Any suggestion?

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: And please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689055/create-an-empty-data-frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Given your desired output you may try this:

```
library(dplyr)  # Gives %>%
dataF <- data.frame(X1 = "aa",
                    X2 = 0,
                    X3 = 0,
                    X4 = 0,
                    X5 = "zz",
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

a <- c("bb")       
b <- c(2, 3, 4)    
c <- c("yy")

# setNames to simply use rbind()
newrow <- data.frame(a, t(b), c, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% setNames(names(dataF))

rbind(dataF, newrow)
```

Which gives you:

```
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ X1: chr  "aa" "bb"
 $ X2: num  0 2
 $ X3: num  0 3
 $ X4: num  0 4
 $ X5: chr  "zz" "yy"
```

#### And guessing your even more desired output:

```
library(dplyr)
dataF <- data.frame(X1 = character(),
                    X2 = numeric(),
                    X3 = numeric(),
                    X4 = numeric(),
                    X5 = character(),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

a <- c("bb")       
b <- c(2, 3, 4)    
c <- c("yy")

newrow <- data.frame(a, t(b), c, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% setNames(names(dataF))

rbind(dataF, newrow)
```

Which gives you:

```
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ X1: chr "bb"
 $ X2: num 2
 $ X3: num 3
 $ X4: num 4
 $ X5: chr "yy"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can just do

```
x <- c("aa", 0, 0, 0, "zz") 
a <- c("bb")       
b <- c(2, 3, 4)    
c <- c("yy")   
y <- c(a, b, c)
rbind(r1 = x,r2 =  y)


#   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#r1 "aa" "0"  "0"  "0"  "zz"
#r2 "bb" "2"  "3"  "4"  "yy"
```

This is a matrix, to get it as a data frame, you can

```
data.frame(rbind(r1 = x,r2 =  y))

#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
#r1 aa  0  0  0 zz
#r2 bb  2  3  4 yy
```