# Read several files in different directories in r

Tags: r, csv

I want to read multiple .csv files from differents directories then put it in a single dataframe.

I have two kinds of directories to read:

A:/LogIIS/FOLDER**01**/"**files.csv**"

---

On others there a folder with several files.csv, as the example bellow:

A:/LogIIS/FOLDER**02**/FOLDER_**A**/"**files.csv**

"A:/LogIIS/FOLDER**02**/FOLDER_**B**/"**files.csv**"

"A:/LogIIS/FOLDER**02**/FOLDER_**C**/"**files.csv**"

---

"A:/LogIIS/FOLDER**03**/FOLDER_**A**/"**files.csv**"

"A:/LogIIS/FOLDER**03**/FOLDER_**B**/"**files.csv**"

"A:/LogIIS/FOLDER**03**/FOLDER_**C**/"**files.csv**"

"A:/LogIIS/FOLDER**03**/FOLDER_**D**/"**files.csv**"

---

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would also use the the `list.files()` function with a loop to extract all information. list all directories under the common top level directory in this case the directory A:/LogIIS

```
common_path = "A:/LogIIS/"
primary_dirs = list.files(common_path);
primary_dirs 
[1] "FOLDER01" "FOLDER02" "FOLDER03"
```

now I would do a nested loop over all `primary_dirs`, in your example all the `.csv` files have a common name `files.csv` which simplifies the problem, you also haven't said how to append the csv files but I will assume they have the same column headers and will use `cbind()` to append them, otherwise you could use `rbind()`

```
main_data = data.frame(##populate heade) ##
```

using the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689055/create-an-empty-data-frame)

```
for(dir in primary_dirs) {
  sub_folders = list.files(paste(common_path,dir,sep = ""))
  if (any(sub_folders %in% "files.csv")) {
    ## there is files.csv in this directory read it in and append to a data.frame.
    ## read in data 
    temp_data = read.csv(file = paste(common_path,dir,"/files.csv",sep = ""))
    ## append
    main_data = cbind(main_data,temp_data);
  } else {
    ## try go one more directory deeper
    for(sub_dir in sub_folders) {
      sub_sub_files = list.files(paste(common_path,dir,"/",sub_dir,sep = ""))             
      if (any(sub_sub_files %in% "files.csv")) {
        ## found files.csv read it in and append it
        temp_data = read.csv(file = paste(common_path,dir,"/",sub_dir,"/files.csv",sep = ""))
        main_data = cbind(main_data,temp_data);
      } else {
        warning("could not find the file 'files.csv' two directories deep")
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to explicitly define a file pattern (a file name, or extension), you can use the `pattern` parameter in the `list.files` function.

```
library(data.table)

# make an explicit alist of folders
folders = list(
  file.path('A:','LogIIS','FOLDER02','FOLDER_A'),
  file.path('A:','LogIIS','FOLDER02','FOLDER_B'),
  file.path('A:','LogIIS','FOLDER02','FOLDER_C'),
  file.path('A:','LogIIS','FOLDER03','FOLDER_A'),
  file.path('A:','LogIIS','FOLDER03','FOLDER_B'),
  file.path('A:','LogIIS','FOLDER03','FOLDER_C'),
  file.path('A:','LogIIS','FOLDER03','FOLDER_D')
)

# iterate through each folder in list and return all files
# unlist those lists of files into a single vector
files = unlist(sapply(folders, function(folder) {
  list.files(folder, full.names=TRUE)
}))

# read each file into a data.table
# return data.table results as a list
# combine list into a single data.table
rbindlist(use.names=TRUE, fill=FALSE,
  lapply(files, function(x) { 
    fread(x)  
  }) 
)
```

Comment: @Mikuma, the code is returning
" Error in fread(x) : 
  Expected sep (' ') but new line, EOF (or other non printing character) ends field 5 when detecting types from point 0: #Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.5 "

Comment: @helio7sr it looks like you have some irregular characters in your CSV files. You may need to either look into cleansing your CSV files, or changing the way that `fread` interprets them. Try the command `?data.table::fread` to read more about the parameters for interpreting your source files.