# Import several files from different directory (but similar structure in every case)

Tags: r, dataframe, import, directory, xlsx

I'm new in the R world, so I have this question:

- I have a principal folder. In that folder, I have several subfolders, and then, into this subfolders, anothers subfolders. For example:

Works/Folder A,B,C.../Economic/New/File.xlsx

This structure repeats for Folder A, B, C, D, and the rest. 
What I need is import every "file.xlsx" and merge all dataframes into one.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried anything? SO has several similar questions that if you search something like [`[r] read multiple files`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+read%20multiple%20files), you'll find several really good matches. I suspect that https://stackoverflow.com/q/5319839 will suffice as a duplicate.

Comment: @r2evans That I guess is to create separate dataframes. I think OP needs one dataframe in the end. There might be a better target but I think this would work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43900965/read-several-files-in-different-directories-in-r

Comment: You're right, they'll need `do.call(rbind, ...)` or `dplyr::bind_rows` or `data.table::rbindlist` after that.

Answer (score 1):

An approach using `map_df`, `list.files`.  Assuming that your files all hold their data on the first worksheet.

```
library(tidyverse)
myConcat <- 
  list.files("Economic/New", recursive = TRUE, pattern = 
            "(?i)file.xlsx", full.names=TRUE) %>% 
  map_df( ~ readxl::read_excel(.x, sheet = 1))

# Runs and works on my own files, (with different directories and names, of course.)
```

The `(?i)` makes it case insensitive; I noticed you had both *File.xlsx* and *file.xlsx*.

Comment: Thanks you. I have one doubt. Economic/New subfolders are in a main folder. Do I need to set the code at that directory?

Comment: Yes.  Or pass `list.files` an absolute path.