# How to store a folder containing over 30 zipped files into a variable in r

Tags: r, csv, zip

I used the package 'GDELTtools' to download data from GDELT. Now, the data was downloaded however, no variable was stored in the global environment. I want to store the data into a dataframe variable so I can analyze it.

The folder contains over 30 zipped files. Every zipped file contains one csv. I need to store all these csvs in one variable in the Global Environment of r. I hope this can be done.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Haven't written R for a while so I will try my best.

Read the comments **carefully**, cause they will explain the **procedure**.

I will attach the links to check information for: [unzip](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/unzip.html), [readCSV](http://rprogramming.net/read-csv-in-r/), [mergeDataFrames](https://www.statmethods.net/management/merging.html), [emptyDataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689055/create-an-empty-data-frame), [concatinateStrings](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Strings/Creating_strings_from_variables/)

According to [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GDELTtools/GDELTtools.pdf) of GDELTtools you can easily specify folder of download by providing *local.folder="~/gdeltdata"* as parameter to GetGDELT() function.

After that you can *list.files("path/to/files/directory")* function to obtain a vector of file names used in the explanation code bellow. Check the [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/list.files.html) for more examples and explanation.

```
# set path to of unzip output
outDir <-"C:\\Users\\Name\\Documents\\unzipfolder"
# relative path where zip files are stored
relativePath <- "C:\\path\\to\\my\\directory\\"
# create varible to store all the paths to the zip files in a vector
zipPaths <- vector()
# since we have 30 files we should iterate through
# I assume you have a vector with file names in the variable fileNames
for (name in fileNamesZip) {
  # Not sure if it will work but use paste() to concat strings
  zipfilepath <- paste0(relativePath, name, ".zip")
  # append filepath
  append(zipPaths, zipfilepath)
}
# now we have a vector which contains all the paths to zip files
# use unzip() function and pass zipPaths to it. (Read official docs)
unzip(files=zipPaths, exdir=outDir)
# initialize dataframe for all the data. You must provide datatypes for the columns.
total <- data.frame=(Doubles=double(),
             Ints=integer(),
             Factors=factor(),
             Logicals=logical(),
             Characters=character(),
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
# now its time to store data by reading csv files and storing them into dataframe.
# again, I assume you have a vector with file names in the variable fileNames
for (name in fileNamesCSV) {
  # create the csv file path 
  csvfilepath <- paste0(outDir, name, ".csv")
  # read data from csv file and store in in a dataframe
  dataFrame = read.csv(file=csvfilepath, header=TRUE, sep=",")
  # you will be able to merge dataframes only if they are equal in structure. Specify the column names to merge by.
  total <- merge(data total, data dataFrame, by=c("Name1","Name2"))
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort. I do not have a vector with the file names. I do not know how I can efficiently gather the names of over 30 files.

Comment: Well, but it seems to be pretty easy to make it work. I'm gonna modify the answer to do that.

Comment: Now I hope it will solve your problem. Good luck with R. It is amazingly beautiful and suitable for data science programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Something potentially much simpler:

1. `list.files()` lists the files in a directory
2. `readr::read_csv()` will automatically unzip files as necessary
3. `dplyr::bind_rows()` will combine data frames

So try:

```
lf <- list.files(pattern="\\.zip")
dfs <- lapply(lf,readr::read_csv)
result <- dplyr::bind_rows(dfs)
```