# R - How can I create an "empty" dataframe after transposing?

Tags: r, dataframe, populate

After transposing my data I am right now at this stage:

| Alex Aro | Billie Piper | Chris Fe | Daron Chlim | Erik Fuc | (3000 more names) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Only headers, but no data inside. Now I want to populate the empty dataframe like this:

| Alex Aro | Billie Piper | Chris Fe | Daron Chlim | Erik Fuc | (3000 more names) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| (18 000 rows) | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |

It does not matter if I have zeros or NA in the end. As you can see lots of rows and columns, so code is only useful if I do not have to type every row  and column by myself. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question has been aswered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48833807/initialize-an-empty-tibble-with-column-names-and-0-rows/57734431#57734431).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You subset the empty dataframe. If the dataframe with headers is called `df` to create 18000 rows with `NA` values you can do -

```
out <- df[1:18000, ]
rownames(out) <- NULL
out
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is looking for. From what I understood, he wants to turn row names into column names and viceversa in an empty df.

Comment: Nope that definitely answered my question. Thanks guys!