# Create a data frame from vector, using the values as columns

Tags: r

Is there a convenient way to create a data frame from a vector and using the values of the vector as column names? Result should only have 1 row with empty fields. Values in vector may vary.

Given:

```
x <- c("1","2","3")
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  `1`   `2`   `3`  
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 ""    ""    ""
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Initialize an empty tibble with column names and 0 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48833807/initialize-an-empty-tibble-with-column-names-and-0-rows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're a tidyverse fan as I see by your using of `tibble`, you could use a combination of `map_dfc` and `setNames`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- x %>% map_dfc(setNames, object = list(character(1)))

df
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 1 x 3
>  `1`   `2`   `3`  
>  <chr> <chr> <chr>
> 1 ""    ""    ""
> ```

Comment: I like tidyverse, and your answer looks good to me, but its mising the 1 row with empty ("") fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x = c("1","2","3")

df = data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 0))
names(df) = x

Output:
> df
[1] 1 2 3

> str(df)
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ 1: logi 
 $ 2: logi 
 $ 3: logi
```

**Update:**

```
df = data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 1))
colnames(df) = x
> df
   1  2  3
1 NA NA NA
```

Comment: Not 100% what i wanted but i can work with that, so thank you!

Comment: I just updated it, now it's with a first empty row. Does this help? If you need "" instead of NA, you could add `df[is.na(df)] = ""`.

Comment: This would work, thank you! The other answer is a bit more compact, so i have to give the accepted answer to that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pivot_wider`:

```
library(tidyr)
data.frame(x) %>%
  pivot_wider(x, 
              names_from = x, values_from = x,
              values_fn = function(x) "")
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  `1`   `2`   `3`  
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 ""    ""    ""
```

Comment: This is also a nice solution. Thank you!