# How to set the types of columns in an empty data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, types, coercion

I need to `union` a result set into this data.frame, in order to make sure I have the columns in place, even if the result set does not contain them.  This is for the purposes of writing to a MySQL DB later on.

```
dbNames <- c('a','b','c','d')
emptyTableOut <- data.frame(
  cbind(
    matrix(character(), ncol = 1, nrow = 0), # needs to be char
    matrix(integer(), ncol = 3, nrow = 0) # needs to be int
  ), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
  setNames(nm = c(dbNames))
> glimpse(emptyTableOut)
Observations: 0
Variables: 4
$ a <chr> 
$ b <chr> 
$ c <chr> 
$ d <chr>
```

How can I do this in a way that doesn't coerce the `int`s to `char`s?

This question is different than the already posted answers because I have a huge number of columns, not the few implied by this minimally reproducible example.

Comment: `data.frame(a = character(0),b = integer(0),c = integer(0),d = integer(0),stringsAsFactors = F)`. The persistence of `cbind(matrix())` stuff in creating data frames continues to amaze me. It just won't die! ;)

Comment: You are way overthinking this. Why are you making those `matrix` calls. Just do `data.frame(a = character(),b = integer(),c = logical(),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: Or `setNames(data.frame(character(0),integer(0),stringsAsFactors = F),c('a','b'))` if you need to set the column names programmatically.

Comment: @joran this question is different and (don't want) to do what you're saying because I have a huge number of columns (see edit).  is it really most efficient to say `character(), integer(),integer(),integer(),integer(),integer(),integer(),integer(),integer(),integer(),integer(),integer(),integer(),integer()`?

Comment: There are other good options at the duplicate: subsetting an existing df, a clever use of read.table.

Comment: @joran this did exactly what i want `emptyTableOut <- data.frame(character(), matrix(integer(), ncol = 3, nrow = 0), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
  setNames(nm = c(dbNames))`.  if Rich Scriven reopens I will answer it myself

Comment: I would add it as an answer at the linked duplicate.

Comment: For people finding this in the future, the reason this problem occurs is that a `matrix` can only have a single data type. When you `cbind` 2 matrices, the result is still a `matrix` and so the variables are all coerced into a single type before converting to a `data.frame`.