# readr:type_convert() fails with substring errors

Tags: r, tibble, readr

I am trying to initialise an empty tibble, with column names column types already specified.

code below successfully initialise an empty tibble with names

```
coltest <- 
  c("exectime", "jancode", "publisher_code", "price_a", "price_b", "title", 
  "date", "star", "purchase", "caption", "reviewer", "comment", "item_info")
dd <- matrix(ncol = 13, nrow = 0) %>% as.data.frame() %>% as_tibble 
colnames(dd) <- coltest
```

I then try to convert all columns to specific types using read::type_convert() shorthand

```
dd %>% type_convert(dd, col_types = "tcfnnfDcfcfcc")
```

This gives error,

```
Error in substring(col_types, idx, idx) : invalid substring arguments
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am afraid it doesn't work in that way. You need something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689055/create-an-empty-data-frame

Comment: Thank you for the reply Ronak! It's nice to know "it won't work" from someone knowledgable like you ;) Will try the methods you suggested. I guess tidyverse/readr verbs are not designed to deal with data that is not there yet.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate the suggestion this may be a duplicate. However I'd like to note that my question is very specifically about "how to deal with readr::type_convert() error message". Initialising an empty data frame is a solution, but does not directly answer my original question. I'm planning to add a solution here if you could leave my original question I think it will be beneficial to others who may be experiencing the same error message.

Comment: ok..reopened. You can add an answer now.