# R/dplyr function: Frequency table including totals of grouping variables

Tags: r, function, dplyr, tidyverse, magrittr

I am working with data from a household survey for which I want to calculate frequency tables of responses to various questions (multiple answers per respondent are possible). To speed up the analysis of the survey data I have written a few local functions while trying to stay in the `tidyverse` logic. I have successfully written a function that allows me to calculate frequencies while using grouping variables.

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

my_df <- tibble(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 8),
                country = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
                region = c("ax", "ax", "ax", "ay", "ay", "bx", "bx", "by", "by", "by"),
                district = c("ax1", "ax1", "ax2", "ay1", "ay2", "bx1", "bx1", "by1", "by1", "by1"),
                question = c("answer1", "answer2", "answer1", "answer2", "answer1", "answer1", "answer1", "answer2", "answer1", "answer2"))

freq <- function(df, var, id_var, ...) {
  
  n <- df %>%
    group_by(...) %>% 
    summarise(n = NROW(unique({{id_var}})), .groups = "drop") %>% 
    left_join(distinct(df, {{var}}), by = character(), .)
  
  df %>%
    group_by(..., {{var}}) %>%
    summarise(cases = n(), .groups = "drop") %>%
    left_join(n) %>%
    mutate(freq_answer = cases/n*100) %>%
    ungroup()
}

my_df %>% 
  freq(question, id, country, region)

# A tibble: 7 x 6
  country region question cases     n freq_answer
  <chr>   <chr>  <chr>    <int> <int>       <dbl>
1 A       ax     answer1      2     2         100
2 A       ax     answer2      1     2          50
3 A       ay     answer1      1     2          50
4 A       ay     answer2      1     2          50
5 B       bx     answer1      2     2         100
6 B       by     answer1      1     2          50
7 B       by     answer2      2     2         100
```

For reporting purposes, in some cases I want to calculate the frequencies for each grouping level and combine the results in a single dataframe. I have found a solution that lets me do this for a fixed number of grouping variables and I am able to get the desired result. Obviously, if I use more or less grouping variables I would have to specify additional functions.

```
freq_sum <- function(df, var, id_var, group1, group2) {
  
  df0 <- freq({{df}}, {{var}}, {{id_var}}) %>%
    add_column({{group1}} :="Total", .before = 1) %>% 
    add_column({{group2}} :="Total", .after = 1)
  
  df1 <- freq({{df}}, {{var}}, {{id_var}}, {{group1}}) %>%
    add_column({{group2}} :="Total", .after = 1)
  
  df2 <- freq({{df}}, {{var}}, {{id_var}}, {{group1}}, {{group2}})
  
  rbind(df2, df1, df0)
  
}

my_df %>% 
  freq_sum(question, id, country, region)

   country region question cases     n freq_answer
   <chr>   <chr>  <chr>    <int> <int>       <dbl>
 1 A       ax     answer1      2     2       100  
 2 A       ax     answer2      1     2        50  
 3 A       ay     answer1      1     2        50  
 4 A       ay     answer2      1     2        50  
 5 B       bx     answer1      2     2       100  
 6 B       by     answer1      1     2        50  
 7 B       by     answer2      2     2       100  
 8 A       Total  answer1      3     3       100  
 9 A       Total  answer2      2     3        66.7
10 B       Total  answer1      3     4        75  
11 B       Total  answer2      2     4        50  
12 Total   Total  answer1      6     7        85.7
13 Total   Total  answer2      4     7        57.1
```

**My question:** Does anyone have any suggestions on how to make the `freq_sum` function more general/elegant which does not require the prior specification of the number of grouping variables?

I had some initial ideas on how to achieve this but am not sure how to implement them or whether they are feasible in the first place.

```
freq_sum <- function(df, var, id, ...) {
  
  df0 <- df %>% 
    freq({{var}}, {{id}}, ...)
  
  grouping_vars <- df0 %>% 
    select(1:{{var}}) %>%
    select(-last_col()) %>% 
    names()
  
  # From grouping_vars create a list with vectors that contain increasingy less grouping variables.
  [1] "country" "region" "district"
  [2] "country" "region"
  [3] "country"
  
  # Use the elements of the list as input in the freq() function.
  # Add the missing grouping variables to the resulting data frames.
  # Combine all dataframes in a single data frame.
  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone has a similar problem: With the help of the answers to the two questions below, I found a solution involving a for loop that works as intended and lets me freely chose the number of grouping variables to be summarised.

[R: Create empty tibble/data frame with column names coming from a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58431789/r-create-empty-tibble-data-frame-with-column-names-coming-from-a-vector/58432288#58432288)

[Adding column if it does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45857787/adding-column-if-it-does-not-exist/53691922#53691922)

```
freq_sum <- function(df, var, id_var, ...) {
   
  var_names <- names(select(df, ...))
  df_total <- bind_rows(setNames(rep("Total", length(var_names)), var_names))
  df_final <- df %>% freq({{var}}, {{id_var}}, ...)
  
  for (i in 1:length(var_names)-1) {
    
    v <- var_names[1:i]
    
    df_final <- df %>%
      freq({{var}}, {{id_var}}, across(v)) %>% 
      add_column(!!!df_total[!names(df_total) %in% names(.)]) %>% 
      rbind(df_final,.) %>% 
      distinct()
  }
  
  df %>%
    freq({{var}}, {{id_var}}) %>%
    add_column(!!!df_total[!names(df_total) %in% names(.)]) %>%
    rbind(df_final, .)
}

my_df %>% 
  freq_sum(question, id, country, region)

# A tibble: 13 x 6
   country region question cases     n freq_answer
   <chr>   <chr>  <chr>    <int> <int>       <dbl>
 1 A       ax     answer1      2     2       100  
 2 A       ax     answer2      1     2        50  
 3 A       ay     answer1      1     2        50  
 4 A       ay     answer2      1     2        50  
 5 B       bx     answer1      2     2       100  
 6 B       by     answer1      1     2        50  
 7 B       by     answer2      2     2       100  
 8 A       Total  answer1      3     3       100  
 9 A       Total  answer2      2     3        66.7
10 B       Total  answer1      3     4        75  
11 B       Total  answer2      2     4        50  
12 Total   Total  answer1      6     7        85.7
13 Total   Total  answer2      4     7        57.1
```