# How to set placeholders in R

Tags: r

```
df1 <- 
structure(c(3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("aaa", "bbb", 
"ccc"), class = c("ordered", "factor"))

df2 <-
structure(c(1L, NA, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("aaa", "bbb", 
"ccc"), class = c("ordered", "factor"))

df3 <- 
structure(c(3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("ddd", "eee", "fff"
), class = c("ordered", "factor"))

dftest1 <- 
structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 
1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1L, NA, 2L), levels = c("AAA", "BBB"
), class = "factor")

dftest2 <-
structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 
1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 
1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = "CCC", class = "factor")
```

I want to put `df1`, `df2` and `df3` (in my case factors) together as placeholders `vars2use`, so to speak.

```
var2use <- c(var1, var2, var3)
```

This placeholder should then be combined with other factors (`dftest1`, `dftest2`) into a data set.

This implementation works as expected:

```
df <- data.frame(dftest1, dftest2, df1, df2, df3)
```

I was hoping that it could also be implemented in this form:

```
df <- data.frame(dftest1, dftest2, var2use)
```

But I get an error:

```
Error in data.frame(dftest1, dftest2, var2use): 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 82, 3
```

The background is that I would like to work with placeholders of this type in different places. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. So you are saying the `df1` value is a simple factor vector and not a data.frame itself? Normally you could `cbind()` additional columns to create a new data.frame rather than call `data.frame()`. Is there a reason you are storing the variable names in strings rather than just putting the data directory in an object?

Comment: perhaps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58431789/create-empty-tibble-data-frame-with-column-names-coming-from-a-vector

Comment: @MrFlick I added reproducible examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more direct way to do this is to just put your values in to a separte data.frame and then `cbind()` the values when you need them. For example

```
vars2use <- data.frame(df1, df2, df3)
df <- cbind(data.frame(dftest1, dftest2), vars2use)
# df <- data.frame(dftest1, dftest2) |> cbind(vars2use) # alternative syntax
```

If for some reason those names really do need to be a character vector, you can use `mget()` to get the values before using `cbind`

```
varnames <- c("df1", "df2", "df3")
df <- cbind(data.frame(dftest1, dftest2), mget(varnames))
```