# Creating/Populating Empty Data Frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation, populate

I am working with R. I found this link here on creating empty data frames in R: [Create an empty data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689055/create-an-empty-data-frame) .

I tried to do something similar:

```
df <- data.frame(Date=as.Date(character()),
                 country=factor(), 
                 total=numeric(), 
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Yet, when I try to populate it:

```
df$total = 7
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, total, value = 7) : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0

df[1, "total"] <- rnorm(100,100,100)

Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 1, "total", value = c(-79.4584309347689,  : 
  replacement has 100 rows, data has 1
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to specify the row index

```
df[1, "total"] <- 7
```

-output

```
str(df)
#'data.frame':  1 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ Date   : Date, format: NA
# $ country: Factor w/ 0 levels: NA
# $ total  : num 7
```

---

The issue is that when we select a single column and assign on a 0 row dataset, it is not automatically expanding the row for other columns. By specifying the row index, other columns will automatically filled with default `NA`

Regarding the second question (updated), a standard data.frame column is a `vector` and the `length` of the `vector` should be the same as the index we are specifying.  Suppose, we want to expand to 100 rows, change the index accordingly

```
df[1:100, "total"] <- rnorm(100, 100, 100) # length is 100 here
dim(df)
#[1] 100   3
```

Or if we need to cram everything in a single row, then wrap the `rnorm` in a `list`

```
df[1, "total"] <- list(rnorm(100, 100, 100))
```

In short, the `lhs` should be of the same length as the `rhs`.  Another case is when we are assigning from a different dataset

```
df[seq_along(aa$bb), "total"] <- aa$bb
```

---

This can also be done without initialization i.e.

```
df <- data.frame(total = aa$bb)
```

Comment: But why is this necessary? I tried this as well :  df[1, "total"] <- rnorm(100,100,100)
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 1, "total", value = c(-79.4584309347689,  : 
  replacement has 100 rows, data has 1  ... do you know why this is happening? Thank you

Comment: @Noob You are adding 100 elements on a single row.  It can be a list though i.e. `list(rnorm(100, 100, 100))`.  Please note that a standard data.frame column is a `vector` and it assumes the vector to be same  length as the index for row.  If you need to add 100 rows, use `df[1:100, "total"] <- rnorm(100, 100, 100)`

Comment: thank you for all your help. Last question : suppose I already have another data frame that exists (called "aa" with a column "bb"). Will this work? df[1, "total"] <- aa$bb

Comment: @Noob Depends on the length 'bb' you may need `df[seq_along(aa$bb), "total"] <- aa$bb`