# Create empty data tables in R

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say I need to create empty date tables with the following names (create if it doesn't exist in my environment):

```
# names of datatables that should be created
  dt_list <- c("results_1", 
               "results_2",     
               "final_results",   
               "model_results")
```

That is, I need to get empty (no columns) data tables: `results_1`, `results_2`, `final_results`, `model_results` (in reality, I have a much longer list of date labels that should be created if they don't exist).
I read the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689055/create-an-empty-data-frame) but didn't find a suitable solution.

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
# create an empty data.table if not exists
  for(dt in 1:length(dt_list)){
    if(!exists(dt_list[dt])){
      dt_list[dt] <- data.table()
    }
  }

Error in dt_list[dt] <- data.table() : replacement has length zero
```

I would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```r
# create an empty data.table if not exists
for(dt in 1:length(dt_list)){
  if(!exists(dt_list[dt])){
    assign(dt_list[dt], data.table())
  }
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks a lot!